# JSON content(pretty JSON) to JSON string in apex

Tags: json, string, salesforce, apex

I have generated a JSON-encoded content using `JSONGenerator` object(say `gen`). Following code

```
gen.getAsString();
```

is retruning a JSON string but it is **prettified** by default.

I want to convert this prettified JSON string to normal JSON string. How can I do it in apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining JSONGenerator instance as -

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
```

***false*** in above definition will ensure a "non-prettified" version of your JSON string.